# Twig in array not working as expected

Tags: templating, array

I am trying to get an entry type check on an array

```
    {% set landerArray = ['fundingLander','healthLander', 'projectLander', 'publicationLander'] %}
    {% set pageType = entry.type %}
    {% if pageType in landerArray %}
    <p> lander page</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>not lander</p>
    {% endif %}
```

If I use plain text

```
{% if 'fundingLander' in landerArray %}
```

It works, but if pass a variable in i get nothing.
I'm guessing twig thinks that pageType is not a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pageType` variable isn’t a string, but an entry type model (i.e. an object). When treated as a string, Craft renders the entry type handle automatically as a convenience, but in other cases - like in comparisons such as this - you should use the `handle` attribute:

```
{% set pageType = entry.type.handle %}
```

Comment: AHA the convenience! cheers